# How to modify join conditions CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, join

[That is my Query object dump from debug...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQKmk.jpg)

I want to add more condition in method `JOIN` clause or i want setting default condition when execute joins by CakePHP.

My code:

```
public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query)
{
    if ($query->join()) {
        foreach ($query->join() as $key => &$join) {
            $join['conditions'] = new QueryExpression('"aaaa" = "bbbbb"');
        }

        return $query;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add your Table classes description?

Comment: from controller call function search in model. i want add more conditions in <join> . can you see on the image.

Comment: your image shows nothing. add the code

Comment: please remove your answers (if they not resolve your problem), and add this code samples to your question post, that's not forum-style resource! if there is nothing in the question ppl will pass by

Comment: yes sir... helpme please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [CakePHP Docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html).

I believe you searching something like this:

```
class CustomerTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasOne('User')
            ->setName('User')
            ->setConditions(['User.active' => '1']) // or any other additional clause
            ->setDependent(true);
    }
}
```

I whould sugggest you to use [innerJoinWith](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-innerjoinwith), if you need to hook your normal association behaviour.

As a hardcode solution (that what I cann see from your code samples), read [join method docs](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_join):

```
 $query->join([
   'user' => [
       'table' => 'user',
       'type' => 'INNER',
       'conditions' => '"aaaa" = "bbbbb"'
   ]
]);
```

Now some telepathy,.. abracadabra,... wait-wait,... try this:

```
public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query)
{
    $joins = $query->join();
    if ($joins) {
        foreach ($joins as $key => &$join) {
            if ($key == 'user')
                $join['conditions'] = ($join['conditions'] ? ' AND ' : '') . ' "aaaa" = "bbbbb"';
        }

        return $joins ? $query->join($joins) : $query;
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't use $this->contain();
public function searchUser($condition = array())
{
       $query->andWhere(['cus.id' => $condition['customer_id']])
                ->join([
                    "table" => "user",
                    "alias" => "us",
                    "type" => "INNER",
                    "conditions" => ["us.id = cus.id"]
                ]);
}

then i call function searchUser() in controller and i want add more conditions:
sample: 
"conditions" => ["us.id = cus.id"]  =>  "conditions" => ["us.id = cus.id", " 1 = 1 " ]

Comment: @BaoNguyenQuoc, add this code to question, also please add CakePHP version you using. suppose it's not 3.x

Comment: also, into the question post, please

Comment: @ 2oppin OK. heplme

Comment: @ 2oppin, t executed $query->join() at model. but at Controller i want get and add more conditions. because i want write common function add more conditions whenever execute method join

Comment: @BaoNguyenQuoc, you just should to execute your ->join in beforeFind with params, to add "NEW" association, if you need to overwrite existing association, use $query->join(['something' => 'different_table'], [], true); (it resets joins list and replace it with what you want), but the better option is to use innerJoinWith to create "NEW" association

Comment: a just want add more conditions, not reset... this is big project and it's done.. i just fix.

Comment: can't you share your CustomerTable user association code?
Do not replace it if dont want , add "user2" association, and use it in find.

If you need it to replace for find action in certain controller, then why would you bother to not replace it?

Comment: no way to add more conditions in method join at beforeFind function by CakePHP ? i just only it :P

Comment: there is, repeating, replace "existing" with "existing + what  you want", or PHP:implode(' AND ', [$existing, $whatUWant]), k?

Comment: can you give me that code, please. syntax cakePHP? how?

Comment: wow) seems my thelepathy practice went way better than I thought, seems you found an answer before the update, you cool, @BaoNguyenQuoc! ;)

Comment: tks supported me, my english maybe not good but u understand about i said =))) can i contact to you?

Comment: Thanks you very much! i sended mail